# Google says don't have to use real name in google acct: Do we then share real name privately w/Ad Sense? Or required update google acct to real name?

Tags: youtube, google-adsense-policies

I just created my google account & a youtube channel:  I read the rules carefully before I started:  It clearly stated we do not need to use our real name for our google account, so for privacy, I did not.

I assumed that to do Ad Sense I would be sharing my real name privately w/Ad Sense.  But am reading conflicting comments in google help & am now really confused as to what I'm supposed to do:

Do I need to change my google acoount to my real name?  Will I still be able to have only my nickname visible on youtube, my youtube channel, & on emails  I send on my google acct; or will my last name be viewable in any of those places?

Will I have verification problems if I try changing to my real name on my google & youtube accounts?

I saw a video that you could only have your chosen username visible, not your real name; if you adjusted something to do w/your google+ page... but on google help it says you need to contact Google team to do that...so which is true?

Thanx so much for taking the time to answer!